# Write multiple dataframes to a single text file without any delimiters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, export

I have 5 different data frames that I'd like to output to a single text file one after the other.

Because of my specific purpose, I do not want a delimiter.

What is the fastest way to do this?

Example:
Below are 5 dataframes. Space indicates new column.

```
 1st df   AAA 1 2 3 4 5 6
 2nd      BBB 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
 3rd      CCC 1 2 3 4 5 6 6 7 12 2 3 3 4 51  2 
          CCC 1 2 3 4 5 6 6 7 12 2 3 3 4 51  2 
 4th      DDD 1 2 3 4 5 6 2 3 4 5 
 5th      EEE 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1 2 2
```

I'd like convert the above to below in a single text file:

```
AAA123456
BBB12345678910 
CCC12345667122334512 
CCC12345667122334512 
DDD1234562345 
EEE12345678910122
```

Notice that columns are just removed but rows are preserved with new lines.

I've tried googling around but to_csv seems to require a delimiter and I also came across a few solutions using "with open" and "write" but that seems to require iterating through every row in the dataframe.

Appreciate any ideas!

Thanks,

Comment: What happens if you try `df.to_csv(filename, sep = '')`?

Comment: it gives me a TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the dataframes with `pd.concat`.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'AAA': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}).T
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'BBB': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}).T
df_all = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Output (which you can format as you see necessary):

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
AAA     1   2   3   4   5   6   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
BBB     1   2   3   4   5   6   7.0     8.0     9.0     10.0
```

Write to CSV [edit: with a creative delimiter]:

```
df_all.to_csv('df_all.csv', sep = ',')
```

Import the CSV and remove spaces:

```
with open('df_all.csv', mode = 'r') as file_in:
    with open('df_all_no_spaces.txt', mode = 'w') as file_out:
        text = file_in.read()
        text = text.replace(',', '')
        file_out.write(text)
```

There's gotta be a more elegant way to do that last bit, but this works. Perhaps for good reason, pandas doesn't support exporting to CSV with no delimiter.

Edit: you can write to CSV with commas and then remove them. :)

Comment: yeah i thought about doing this... except my dataframe has some intentional spaces as values. surely this would erase all that, right?

Comment: In that case, use a pipe (|) or some other character that doesn't actually appear in your data as the delimiter when writing, so you can remove it safely.

Comment: ah of course.. not sure why that escaped me... thank you for the idea!

Comment: like a comma :)

Answer (score 0):

to gather some data frame in single text file do:

```
whole_curpos = ''
#read every dataframe
for df in dataframe_list:
  #gather all the column in a single column
  df['whole_text'] = df[col0].astype(str)+df[col1]+...+df[coln]
  for row in range(df.shape[0]):
    whole_curpos = whole_curpos + df['whole_text'].iloc[row]
  whole_curpos = whole_curpos + '\n'
```